# Efficient method of deleting rows in a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

Is there better method of deleting rows in an excel spreadsheet than than what I currently use?

On a spreadsheet I run a macro that deletes a row if a figure in a particular cell is '0'.

```
Public Sub deleteRowsIfZero(colDelete As Integer)
Dim r As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For r = Cells(Rows.Count, colDelete).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(r, colDelete).Value = "0" Then Rows(r).Delete
Next r
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This works, but with a spreadsheet of 700+ rows it can be quite slow. Is there a more efficient method to do this?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Cheers

Noel

Comment: Are you using `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`?

Comment: @JamieBull Yes I am using Application.ScreenUpdating = False, have amended my question.

Comment: rowDelete should be colDelete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off screen updating and calculation before you begin and restore those settings at the end.

Note that you are unnecessarily retesting a row every time you delete because the deletion slides the rows up. Therefore you could decrement `r` each time you do a deletion for a small optimization.

A further optimization would be to read in all the test values at one time. Each read/write from/to Excel/VBA has an overhead. See example below:

```
Dim r As Long, n As Long
Dim testcells As Variant

n = Cells(Rows.count, rowdelete).End(xlUp).Row
testcells = Range(Cells(n, rowdelete), Cells(1, rowdelete)).Value

For r = n To 1 Step -1
    If testcells(r, 1) = 0 Then
        Rows(r).Delete
    End If
Next r
```

You can also try deleting all at once to see which is faster.

```
Dim r As Long, n As Long
Dim testcells As Variant
Dim del As Range

n = Cells(Rows.Count, rowdelete).End(xlUp).Row
testcells = Range(Cells(n, rowdelete), Cells(1, rowdelete)).Value

For r = n To 1 Step -1
    If testcells(r, 1) = 0 Then
        If del Is Nothing Then Set del = Rows(r)
        Set del = Union(del, Rows(r))
    End If
Next r

If Not (del Is Nothing) Then
    del.Delete
End If
```

Comment: have amended the question as I had screen updating turned off. Have turned off calculation also and it appears that there may have been a slight improvement. On faster machines this isn't a major issue, but on slower machines it takes a while to loop through.

Comment: @noelmcg Added some other things for you to try out.

Comment: @noelmcg And another... Try these and Jüri Ruut's solution and let us know which works best for you!

Comment: Cheers @A.Webb, i'm getting an "error 91 object variable or with variable not set" on the line "del.Delete". Apart from that it rocks!

Comment: i added the following " If Not (del Is Nothing) Then
del.Delete
End If" Works a treat

Comment: Ah, yes, those pesky edge cases!

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a contiguous range and delete it in one go:

```
Public Sub deleteRowsIfZero(strSeekValue As String)
Dim lngRowsToDelete() As Long
Dim strRowsToDelete() As String
Dim x As Long, y As Long, n As Long, z As Long

On Error GoTo err_

'get the extent of the workbook range
x = Me.UsedRange.Rows.Count

n = -1

'switch off screen updating and calculation
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'starting from row 1, look for the strSeekValue in column A, keep going till x is reached
For y = 1 To x
    If Me.Range("A" & y).Value = strSeekValue Then 'if we find one, pop the row number into the array
        n = n + 1
        ReDim Preserve lngRowsToDelete(0 To n)
        lngRowsToDelete(n) = y
    End If
Next y

'if none were found, don't do the next bit
If n = -1 Then GoTo err_

'create a string of all the rows we found
z = 0
ReDim strRowsToDelete(z)
For y = 0 To n
    strRowsToDelete(z) = strRowsToDelete(z) & lngRowsToDelete(y) & ":" & lngRowsToDelete(y) & ","
    If Len(strRowsToDelete(z)) > 240 Then 'As A.Webb points out, the 255 limit will be a problem here
        strRowsToDelete(z) = Left(strRowsToDelete(z), Len(strRowsToDelete(z)) - 1) 'drop the trailing comma
        z = UBound(strRowsToDelete) + 1 'resize the array
        ReDim Preserve strRowsToDelete(0 To z)
    End If
Next y

For y = z To 0 Step -1
    If Right(strRowsToDelete(z), 1) = "," Then strRowsToDelete(z) = Left(strRowsToDelete(z), Len(strRowsToDelete(z)) - 1)
    'now delete the rows
    Me.Range(strRowsToDelete(y)).EntireRow.Delete
Next y

err_:
'assumes calculation was set to auto
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
If Err Then Debug.Print Err.Description
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


'run sub foo
Sub foo()
deleteRowsIfZero "0"
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you'll find that when strRowsToDelete exceeds 255 characters, which could occur for as few as 43 2-digit row numbers for example, this code will fail at the Range(strRowsToDelete).

Comment: @Zilpher I've tried this, and with a little alteration to suit my needs, it absolutely zips through it!

Comment: @Zilpher this works great but I am going to go with A.Webb's solution. Thanks for showing me a different technique.

Answer (score 0):

If there are few errors expected, it should be quicker to find matching cells and delete them. Column D is serving for holding characters for deleting.

```
Sub DeleteRowWithCertainValue()

Dim del_char As String

 del_char = "0"

Do
  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
     Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D:D").Find(What:=del_char, _
        After:=Range("D1"), _
          LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
           SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
          SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False).EntireRow.Delete
Loop

ErrorHandler: Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on a different technique but I'm going to go with A.Webbs solution

Comment: I got some work done for the future :-) Btw, it would be interesting to get times to complete the task for all code variants.

Comment: @noelmcg Time taken by a procedure: http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=542